# Why is the type of a dat.gui instance so long and nested?

Tags: javascript

[dat.gui](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#1--Basic-Usage) seems like a relatively simple javascript library. So why on earth, when you instantiate it, does it return a dat.GUI.dat.gui.GUI.GUI ?

[image: instantiating dat.gui]

EDIT: I guess I am failing to explain myself well here. This is a WHY question -- presumably the authors of dat.gui didn't want to do it this way, but for some reason they had to nest like crazy. Could the downvoters please provide some criticism so I know what I'm doing wrong here?

EDIT, still trying to explain myself: I'd like an answer that puts this in the context of javascript style and conventions. Is this just bad code? Is there some reason that a prototype-based language leads to extra type nesting? Is dat.gui designed to do a lot more than I realize and there's actually a use for a dat.GUI.dat.gui?

Comment: if you actually open the [dat.gui](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dataarts/dat.gui/master/build/dat.gui.js) file you will notice that its not as simple as the small example in your question.

Comment: Banana, I'm not sure what you mean by that, or why it's relevant to the question. dat.gui is 3.6K lines, so it's short compared to something like openlayers, three.js, d3, jquery, whatever. When I said simple, though, I meant it does a simple thing -- it puts a single widget on a page which allows tweaking of variables. Why would the type of that widget need to be so deeply nested?

Comment: Thanks. Also, I'd like the close vote explained. How is this too broad? It seems quite specific. I want to learn what each of the .dat and .GUI in this type represent. These "too broad" votes seem to be the catch-all these days for "I want to close this, but I can't articulate why."

Comment: @foobarbecue dat.gui weighs 98.5 KB, and if you look inside you will find the nesting.

Comment: I know. The question is: why? Is it just bad code? Obviously I haven't read enough to know. I'm hoping someone on stackoverflow already knows the answer, which is generally what one hopes when one asks a question...

Comment: @foobarbecue areyou really expecting someone to read 3.6K lines just to explain to you why the author of the plugin decided to do what he did? ask the author.

Comment: @Banana, that's ridiculous.

Comment: I voting to close this since answers would just be speculative.

Comment: I mean, eventually, I guess I'll just read the damn code and answer my own question in a few days with a description of what each level of the nest represents and whether it appears to be necessary. Since this is a heavily-used library, I was hoping someone already knew.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type name is not long and nested after all -- actually it's anonymous. A combination of unusual coding style with a quirk of Chrome Dev Tools makes it appear as it does. It doesn't happen in Firefox.

On [line 1532](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553642/why-does-javascript-concatenate-function-names-in-multiple-assignment-to-propert) of dat.gui.js, the prototype `dat.GUI`, which I was instantiating with `new dat.GUI()`, is created and also assigned to `dat.gui.GUI`:

`dat.GUI = dat.gui.GUI = (function` ...

This function is anonymous. When Chrome Dev Tools prints a representation of an anonymous function that has been assigned to a variable, it pretends the name of the variable is the name of the function for debugging convenience.

For some reason which is discussed but not fully explained [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30553642/why-does-javascript-concatenate-function-names-in-multiple-assignment-to-propert), Chrome concatenates these function pseudonyms in the case where you are assigning an anonymous function to multiple object properties:

[image]

So that's why

`dat.GUI = dat.gui.GUI = (function` ...

prints

`function dat.GUI.dat.gui.GUI()`

in Chrome Dev Tools.