# Why does javascript concatenate function names in multiple assignment to properties?

Tags: javascript, function, object

This is an edge case and probably bad practice, but it made me curious about some js internals. Can anyone explain why chrome dev tools tells me that I have created a function named a.a.b.b here?

[image]

Note that this does not happen unless you are assigning to a property. Otherwise both a and b appear to refer to a function object named 'b':

[image]

By the way, I originally encountered this [here](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui/blob/a65c4f9b3887ba7b2ebd4fecb91d35257ba0705c/build/dat.gui.js#L1532) when trying to answer [my own question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546340/why-is-the-type-of-a-dat-gui-instance-so-long-and-nested) about dat.gui.js .

Comment: You're being misled by the odd ways in which browser consoles work. (The language doesn't do what you think it's doing. Anonymous functions don't really have names.)

Comment: To @Pointy's point, if you try to call a.a.b.b() you'll get a TypeError.

Comment: It has nothing to do with JS internals. It's just a DevTools enhancement, for debugging convenience I guess. The real assigned value is still **anonymous function** - `a.a.name` gives you empty string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This has nothing to do with the language spec.
>   It's a DevTools enhancement for debugging convenience, which is ported recently in Chrome.

Remember what we used to do?

```
function F() {}
// notice it's a NAMED function expression
F.prototype.asdf = function _asdf() { debugger; }; 

var f = new F();
f.asdf();
```

Then in breakpoint debugging, we can find the method by its name `_asdf` from function call stack. Otherwise it's the pain in the ass to do that from a list of **(anonymous function)**.

[image]

In latest Chrome, when you assign an **anonymous** function as an object property, an alias will be attached to it.

```
var a = {}, b = {};
a.a = b.b = function() { debugger; };
a.b = b.a = function _abba() { debugger; };
```

Remember, it's just a DevTools enhancement, the method remains **anonymous**:

```
a.a.name; // ""
a.b.name; // "_abba"
```

But it's very helpful in breakpoint debugging:

```
a.a();
a.b();
```

[image]

---

EDIT:

I'm not very sure why the alias is generated as `a.a.b.b`, it looks very easy but kind of... stupid. However, in practice we seldom do `a.a = b.b = func...` thing (lucky). Instead, we define a method in one place, and do **inheritence** when necessary, rather than copy reference directly.

So in a good programming practice, the alias should and would exactly reflect where you define the method. For example, alias `Dog.bark` in breakpoint clearly maps to `Dog.prototype.bark` in source code, even if it's called on a `Puppy` instance, and we don't have to do old school named function expression.

```
function Dog() {}
Dog.prototype.bark = function() { alert("Woof!") }; // anonymous function expression here
function Puppy() {}
Puppy.prototype = new Dog();

(new Puppy()).bark(); // break point alias -> Dog.bark
```

One more thing, when I discovered this feature, I can't stop thinking of it - does it imply that Chrome will implement ES6 **class** very soon? How exciting!

Comment: Very helpful answer. I had somehow started thinking that a function assigned to a variable is no longer anonymous and you've corrected my understanding of that. I haven't marked it as correct yet because it's still not clear to me why Chrome dev tools does the a.a.b.b thing exactly. You've convinced me that it doesn't matter much, but do you think this was accidental, or by design?

Comment: @foobarbecue I'm not sure why it's `a.a.b.b`, but I added something to my answer, about how we could take advantage of this feature. Another bold conjecture is that (how exciting), Chrome is going to implement ES6 **class** very soon?

Comment: Interesting... I don't really see why the concatenation thing would imply implementation of **class**. Can you explain more? My guess is that it is actually some kind of bug in Chrome Dev Tools.

Comment: @foobarbecue I found something interesting here https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=17356. Read the discussion, especially #44, #49 and #55. So it looks like a feature rather than a bug :D About the implementation of **class**, it's just my guess. I hope it can get real in near future.